# Firebase: How to determine duplicate in different parents

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code to reject duplicates in the "Admin" Firebase:

```
  public static void checkForDuplicateTweet()
  {
    Query adminQuery = dbRefAdminFeed.orderByChild("tweetStatusID").equalTo(TweetData.tweetStatusID);
    Query feedQuery = dbRefFeed.orderByChild("tweetStatusID").equalTo(TweetData.tweetStatusID);

    adminQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
      {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
        {
          boolean isFirst = true;

          for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
          {
            TweetData tweetData = postSnapshot.getValue(TweetData.class);

            if (isFirst)
            {
              isFirst = false;
            }
            else
            {
              removeTweetFromFirebase(Objects.requireNonNull(tweetData).tweetKey);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
      {
      }
    });
  }
```

How do I check a different parent to see if the tweetStatusID exists under that parent with the following structure?

[image: link to firebase screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're halfway there. To check if the value exists under both parents, you have to run a query on each parent. So just run the query on `dbRefFeed`, once you've determine that the value exists under `dbRefAdminFeed`.

```
Query adminQuery = dbRefAdminFeed.orderByChild("tweetStatusID").equalTo(TweetData.tweetStatusID);
Query feedQuery = dbRefFeed.orderByChild("tweetStatusID").equalTo(TweetData.tweetStatusID);

adminQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot adminSnapshot) {
    if (adminSnapshot.exists()) {
      feedQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot feedSnapshot) {
          if (feedSnapshot.exists()) {
              ...
          }
        }
    }
  }
```